# How to create a shortcut or automate file in calling a contact in skype

Tags: macos, mac, skype, automator

What are the option in creating a quick access to dialing a contact in Skype? and How?

Example I want to bind a custom key in calling my friend, let say

> "cmd" + "0"

or

> cmd + "9"

. I'm on the Mac OS X (10.7.3) environment and i'm just looking for a free hack options.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into the options of Skype, or looked if you can right click on a contact and bind this action?

Comment: i checked it with Skype and I can't find any options to do that...